# `akka-http` returns `No Response` for request instead of `Custom Response` specified by `withRequestTimeout` directive for https connection

Tags: scala, https, timeout, akka-http

I’m currently trying to setup `withRequestTimeout` directive for service based on `akka-http`.

```
withRequestTimeout(FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),req =>
HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.InternalServerError, entity = "Request timeout"))
```

For `http` connection it works fine and returns my custom response, but for `https` it usually returns `No Response` and sometimes my custom response. I traced request and it looks like it was cut down before server returned actual response. What can be potential issue that causes it?

Comment: What happens if you increase your timeout to 10 seconds?

Comment: @MatthiasFax tried to play with different timeouts (also 10 seconds as you suggested). Didn't help. The behavior is same for all cases.

Comment: Akka normally logs a warning message in such cases. Can you enable AkkaLogging, the info level of the logging backend and add the message to your question?

Comment: @MatthiasFax I tried to do this before with `akka.loglevel = DEBUG` set up in config. But the only thing that I received when I sent request was just one line: `[DEBUG] [03/28/2017 11:45:03.984] [appname-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] [akka://appname/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] New connection accepted`.

Comment: In that case, we will need more code to analyze your problem. Can you add your https parameters and the route for your custom response?